# invalid opcode "0x1c" during smart contract method execution

Tags: go-ethereum, web3j, solc

I have written a smart contract to test event from java project using web3j
I have prepared the web3j wrapper java class using solc compiler version 
 *"**0.5.7+commit.6da8b019.Linux.g++**"*

I am using a private ethereum network to deploy the smart contract and execute method in smart contract.

The smart contract source is

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.7;

contract TestEvent {

    // Test Event will be received by java application
    event testEvent(string indexed message);


    function emitTestEvent(
        string  calldata message
    ) 
    external
    {
     emit testEvent(message);
    }
}
```

Java code to execute the method is

```
// Load broken smart contract build by solc version 0.5.7
        TestEvent contract = TestEvent.load("0x673ccae08d3c3f50f111fb9e5870c76bbbf60938",
                web3, credentials,
                GAS_PRICE, GAS_LIMIT);  // contract instance
        if (contract != null){
            TransactionReceipt transactionReceipt = contract.emitTestEvent("Message").send();
            System.out.println(transactionReceipt.toString());
        }
```

When executing the emitTestEvent method geth log output shows an error

> "err="invalid opcode 0x1c"

[image]

What is the problem with my source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That opcode is a recent addition to geth in the Constantinople release. You need to add the following to your genesis to enable Constantinople:

```
     "constantinopleBlock":0,
```

Answer (score 4):

Opcode `0x1c` is `SHR` or right shift, which was introduced in the recent update (more [here](https://blog.ethereum.org/2019/02/22/ethereum-constantinople-st-petersburg-upgrade-announcement/)). It was not available prior to February, 2019.

It is likely that your Java tool (`web3j`?) is out dated and does not recognize this opcode. You may be able to upgrade to a newer version which has Constantinople/St. Petersburg support.