# Call smart contract function in geth

Tags: solidity, contract-development

Environment, Ubuntu 18.04:

```
bs@dharma ~/Schau $ geth version
Geth
Version: 1.9.3-stable
Git Commit: cfbb969da803d4cc92e1a64fc1b3c06db299b564
Architecture: amd64
Protocol Versions: [63]
Network Id: 1
Go Version: go1.11.5
Operating System: linux
GOPATH=/home/bs/go/bin
GOROOT=/home/bs/go
```

I am running on a private chain (I'm just experimenting :-).   I'm testing this smart contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Doubler {
    function execute(int a) public pure returns(int) {
        return a + a;
    }
}
```

I compile with:

```
solc -o target --bin --abi Doubler.sol
```

I embed the Doubler.bin and Doubler.abi in a javascript:

```
var doublerFactory = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"internalType":"int256","name":"a","type":"int256"}],"name":"execute","outputs":[{"internalType":"int256","name":"ok","type":"int256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"}]);
var doublerCompiled = "0x6080604052348015600f57600080fd5b5060ad8061001e6000396000f3fe6080604052348015600f57600080fd5b506004361060285760003560e01c8063a04d2faf14602d575b600080fd5b605660048036036020811015604157600080fd5b8101908080359060200190929190505050606c565b6040518082815260200191505060405180910390f35b6000818201905091905056fea265627a7a72315820e98e8a5d85a2c5f21ce56899d6eadc9b93fadf694dba07ba2efbd43c8735b94664736f6c634300050b0032";

var doubler = doublerFactory.new({from:web3.eth.accounts[0],data:doublerCompiled,gas:200000}, function(e, contract) {
    if (e) {
        console.error(e);
        return;
    }

    if (!contract.address) {
        console.log("Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: " + contract.transactionHash + " waiting to be mined...");
    } else {
        console.log("Contract mined! Address: " + contract.address);
    }
})
```

I run geth, and in the console I unlock my account and start the miner:

```
personal.unlockAccount("account", "password", 0)
miner.start()
```

Then I paste the above javascript into the console and after a while I see the messages:

```
Contract transaction send: TransactionHash: 0x7c24585dbd5d2c9757ad5b40cf0180a699dc52563b86c2a8a74db27cc84bb507 waiting to be mined...
Contract mined! Address: 0x04e44901ff037a2d859ca9bbaa05595cec611daa
```

Now, if I run my method:

```
doubler.execute(4)
```

... in this case I'd expect the return value to be 8.  But I get -- a red 0.
No matter the arguments, the return is always a red 0.

I also tried calls such as:

```
doublerFactory.at("0x04e44901ff037a2d859ca9bbaa05595cec611daa").execute(4)
```

Still, a big red 0 back.

I suppose that the color (red) denotes some kind of error.  But what kind of error.   I don't know what I am doing wrong.
Is it the invocation of the method?   Or is the method wrong / flawed?

Comment: Upgradet to geth-1.9.5-stable.  Enabled debugging - now I see this in the logs:  DEBUG[09-23|21:58:41.306] VM returned with error                   err="invalid opcode 0x1c"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yay! Solved - I had to add

```
"constantinopleBlock": 0
```

to my genesis.json in the

```
"config": {
   ...
}
```

section.

It now works - my contract is doubling the input :-)

(See: [invalid opcode "0x1c" during smart contract method execution](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/69530/invalid-opcode-0x1c-during-smart-contract-method-execution))